# How to add elements in an array without index, based on the query expression in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

In my function, I am updating my string DocumentLangaugeString as shown in the code.

Now, I need to add elements to my int[] DocumentLanguagesIds,
The query expression I can use is:
       `from mi in ContextMenuItems where mi.IsChecked select mi.Data.Id`

My int[] is supposed to have items which are checked (IsChecked = true), how do I maintain this array? The function gets called each time a user clicks on the item.

Here the ContextMenuItems is the class property which has the IDs I need to add in my array.

```
private void ClickOnLanguageContextMenu(LanguageContextMenuItemViewModel item)
{
    item.IsChecked = !item.IsChecked;
    DocumentLanguagesString = string.Join(", ", from mi in ContextMenuItems where mi.IsChecked select mi.Data.Description);
    DocumentLanguagesIds = /*need a way to add ids over here*/                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
DocumentLanguagesIds = 
    (from mi in ContextMenuItems where mi.IsChecked select mi.Data.Id)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to not repeat the query also for the `Id` property you can do something like this:

```
var result = (from mi in ContextMenuItems where mi.IsChecked
              select new { mi.Data.Description, mi.Data.Id }).ToList();

DocumentLanguagesString = string.Join(", ", result.Select(x => x.Description));
DocumentLanguagesIds = result.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```

Comment: I needed an int array, so .ToArray() just worked. Thanks.